# Converting cells in a dataframe to binary values if they contain a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column called `player_traits`, which contains zero, one or more traits for each player, e.g. 'Injury Prone', 'Long Shot Taker', 'Power Header' etc.

I want to change this column so that if a cell contains 'Injury Prone' its value is converted to 1, and if the cell does not contain 'Injury Prone' its value is converted to 0

[A screenshot of my dataframe, with `player_traits` on the rightmost column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLHBZ.png)

Any tips much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide example data and the code you have tried?

Comment: sure, I have uploaded a screenshot of my df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will cycle through all of your different traits and assign a binary value for them:

```py
###### Recreate OP's data########
import pandas as pd
traits = ['Injury Prone', 'Long Shot Taker', 'Power Header']
players = ["Player1", "Player2"]
player_traits = ['Injury Prone, Long Shot Taker', 'Power Header']
df = pd.DataFrame({"Player":players, "Player_Traits":player_traits})
#################################

df["Player_Traits"] = [1 if "Injury Prone" in x else 0 for x in df.Player_Traits]
df
```

Ouput:

```
    Player  Player_Traits
0   Player1     1
1   Player2     0
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed post but I don't really understand your binary outputs: 110, 001 etc.

Comment: I simply want a 1 or 0 depending on whether or not 'Injury Prone' is present within the `player_traits` column

Comment: Oh I misread your question. Check the edit

Comment: thank you, I like the look of this. but when I run it I get `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`, even though I know that the `dtype` of `player_traits` is `object` 

Comment: Most likely due to your "NaN" values, you need to convert that entire column to string

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Player_Traits'] = df.Player_Traits.str.contains("Injury Prone").astype(int)
```

Comment: thank you but this returns 0 for every player. I suspect that is because there are no players that have 'Injury Prone' as their only trait